# What happens when you dispatch a task asynchronously inside a sync queue in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

I have found this to produce a deadlock, but I can't figure out why. Basically, I have a queue inside a class and every time the state of the class is supposed to be changed, I run that task inside the queue as a synchronous task:

```
private var serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "my_mutex_queue")
func changeState() {
  serialQueue.sync {
    // perform change
  }
}
```

There are certain changes of state that require a call to a delegate. In this case, the task cannot be called synchronously, because it will cause a deadlock. However, dispatching it asynchronously also results in a deadlock (we are still inside the synchronous task "changeState" in the queue "my_mutex_queue"):

```
func notifyDelegate() {
        serialQueue.async { 
            // notify delegate
        }
}
```

If I run the delegate notification as an asynchronous task *in a different queue*, then everything works as expected.
I couldn't find any note on Apple's documentation on why calling an asynchronous task inside the same queue causes a deadlock.

Comment: Can you provide more information; specifically, how do you call `notifyDelegate` from `changeState`?  What does the delegate do in its function?  I just created a simple test and it did not deadlock when I dispatched asynchronously onto the serial queue

Comment: The code you provided will not create a deadlock on its own. For deadlock to happen you need 2 tasks: task A, running on serial queue is waiting for task B, while task B is waiting inside the same queue for task A to complete. In both cases you need to either complete your task A to let B complete (you can schedule A again to run again after B, so the conditions of execution change), or change how you run things. But more details are needed, as previous poster specified

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry, I forgot to mention that the delegate can trigger other changeState calls. Basically, the sync queue is to perform as an Objective-C "@synchronize". The deadlock comes from there, the delegate call will get trapped when using the same queue. If I use another queue I don't find any problems

Comment: @KirilS. would you say then that if use a different approach, such as ayncAfter, for instance, this won't happen?

Comment: Right. That is your problem. As Eugene said in his answer it is a bad idea to expose your private dispatch queue outside of your class since you don't know what the delegate is going to do. I would dispatch the delegate call onto the main queue or other global queue.  Alternatively, replace your private dispatch queue with a `DispatchSemaphore`. Regardless of which approach you use, avoid calling `changeState` on the main queue.

Comment: @Paulw11 I ended up using the global queue (this is a framework, not an app). I have used the DispatchSemaphore before, as a first implementation, but I was trying to achieve other purposes using the DispatchQueue. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t call `serialQueue.sync` from the block that is being executed by the `serialQueue`.

TL;DR;

Here is what I think is likely happening:

1. You schedule a block A via `serialQueue.async` from `notifyDelegate`.
2. In the context of block A execution, your delegate calls `changeState`, incorrectly assuming that current thread is not the `serialQueue`’s thread.
3. From the `changeState` method, being on the `serialQueue`’s call stack, you schedule synchronously another block B via `serialQueue.sync` which can never start because you wait for it to be started in the previously asynchronously scheduled block A which is currently executed by the `serialQueue`.

Ways to avoid this situation:

1. Never invoke public callbacks in the private serial queue that you use for synchronization.

OR

2. Don’t use private queue for synchronization, use `os_unfair_lock`or `NSLock` or `NSRecursiveLock` instead. It might also improve the performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you hit the nail in the head. The recommendations were really good as well, appreciate it.